# Is there any site/place which gives access to astronomical signals acquired from space?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, astronomy

I am an engineer and I'd like to know if there are any places which provide access to any kind of astronomical signals acquired from space using radio telescopes.

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly, I wasn't able to find anything that seems to be what you are looking for.  Most institutions and research projects keep their data locally, and then only publish the results, using the peer-reviewed process where others will attempt to replicate their results by taking their own observations.  I found A LOT of PDF papers via a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&q=download%20radio%20astronomy%20signals%20site%3a.edu&oq=download%20radio%20astronomy%20signals%20site%3a.edu&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=336011l338204l0l338487l10l10l0l0l0l0l113l729l9.1l10l0&gs_l=serp.3...336011l338204l0l338488l10l10l0l0l0l0l113l729l9j1l10l0), but no database of raw signals, with the exception of [SETI@Home](http://setiathome.berkeley.edu/).  Although, I don't think those signals are in the format that you may be looking for.

Maybe a more direct contact with the [National Radio Astronomy Observatory (NRAO)](http://www.nrao.edu/) will get you some more info?  Although the FAQ didn't indicate that these signals are publicly available, but rather (again) restricted to academia and the associated research they are doing.  [There is a resource list for Radio Astronomy that may be of use to you](http://www.cv.nrao.edu/fits/www/yp_radio.html).

[Cal Tech offers more links to different databases](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Andernach/Ander5.html), but again, it's not the raw signals.  [Some other organizations also have databases](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&q=radio%20astronomy%20database%20site%3a.edu&oq=radio%20astronomy%20database%20site%3a.edu&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=155526l161358l0l162010l9l9l0l0l0l0l78l661l9l9l0&gs_l=serp.3...155526l161358l0l162011l9l9l0l0l0l0l78l661l9l9l0) that you could poke around with.

Hope that helps.